# Specify platform restriction for individual SPM targets

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

The [platforms](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/packagedescription/package/platforms) property in a `Package.swift` file restricts available platforms for the whole package. Is there a way to specify platforms for individual targets or libraries?

I have a Swift package that has a "full" target requiring iOS or tvOS (for UIKit) and a backend (model) sub-target that can also run on watchOS and macOS.

Answer (score 0):

there's this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/packagedescription/target/dependency/target(name:condition:) where you can define conditions per target: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/packagedescription/targetdependencycondition

Comment: IIUC, that's for making dependencies conditional. I'd like to make a specific product only available on a specific platform. Looks like this is currently not possible.

Comment: @OrtwinGentz Have you found a way. I am also having the same issue